# Breaking down 1M row jsonlines file into individual json files - python

Tags: python, memory, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to process hundreds of different files that are of .jl.gz format stored in s3.  I need to take different parts of each of the 1M json objects in these files and move them over to a sql database, a mongodb, and elasticsearch.

This is taking too long.  So, what I've tried so far is feeding all of the files into a SQS queue and then:

```
1) Running multiple screen sessions on ec2 instances to read through them faster.
    - This worked, but was not ideal because of the manual oversight needed
    - From this, I wondered about a way to do the equivalent of running multiple screen sessions from within python and found multiprocessing module.
```

The multiprocessing module appears to do what I want, but I keep running into memory error:

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

when either creating processes for each line in the file OR when creating a queue for each line in the file.  See code for creating queue below.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, Pool, Queue

def create_mp_queue(self, gzf):
    q = Queue()
    for line in gzf:
        q.put(line)
    return q

workers = 2
gzf = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)    
c_queue = create_mp_queue(gzf)

for x in xrange(workers):
    p = Process(target=self.company_to_s3, args=(company_queue,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

So, how do I limit the size of my queue so that I don't run out of memory?  I'm on ec2, so I can ramp up size of server, but would prefer a solution flexible enough to be implemented on any server.

I am open to other modules, methods, tips, tricks, etc for using python to quickly read through large amounts of data.

Comment: Can you provide details on what actually goes into the database? Is it something that requires looking at multiple json objects or one is sufficient? Also how json objects are stored in the .jl.gz format? one json objects per line or one json objects for the whole file? if whole file then what is the max size of these json objects.

Comment: ~1000 BIG .jl.gz files.  EACH .jl.gz file has ~1M json objects separated by new lines (jl format is jsonlines).  Each json object is somewhat standardized information, but needs to be loaded via json loads and then put into a relational database format before being pushed over to mysql.  Other parts of the json objects will be moved to mongo and indexed for search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a global counter that I passed to each processor as opposed to a large queue of numbers.